# How to select multiple pattern from dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset (data) with list of email ids:

```
email=c("susgho.agency@gmail.com","suagencyter.m@gmail.com",
        "duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com","ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com",
        "gjhfhg1-ail.com","gjhgkjhgbrt.gh@aol.com")
```

I have another dataset - (disp) with list of pattern:

```
pattern=c(".agency",".abc","1-ail.com"))
```

I want to see if the pattern matches with the emails.
the expected output should be as follows:

```
email                         pattern
susgho.agency@gmail.com       .agency
suagencyter.m@gmail.com 
duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com       .abc
ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com    
gjhfhg1-ail.com               1-ail.com
gjhgkjhgbrt.gh@aol.com
```

I am using for loop but it is taking forever to execute.

```
w <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(disp))
{
  w1 <- as.character(disp[i,1])
  w2 <- data[grep(w1, data$email),]
  if(nrow(w2) > 0)
  {
    w2$pattern <- w1
    w <- rbind(w, w2)
  }
  else
    w <- rbind(w, w2)
}
```

Any help would e highly appreciated. tia!

Comment: Sorry I quickly realised that as well and removed the comment.

Comment: @JMilner no problem. :) Can you please give me any idea how to find the solution?

Comment: something like ````grep(paste(pattern,collapse="|"),email, value=TRUE)```` would print out the emails with matches, but the output would be different

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df$pattern[max.col(-attr(adist(df2$pattern,df$email,counts = T),'counts')[,,3])] = as.character(df2$pattern)
df
                    email   pattern
1 susgho.agency@gmail.com   .agency
2 suagencyter.m@gmail.com      <NA>
3 duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com      .abc
4    ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com      <NA>
5         gjhfhg1-ail.com 1-ail.com
```

or you could do

```
merge(df,stack(setNames(Vectorize(grep)(df2$pattern,df,value=T,fixed=T),df2$pattern)),by.x="email",by.y = "values",all=T)
                    email       ind
1 duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com      .abc
2    ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com      <NA>
3         gjhfhg1-ail.com 1-ail.com
4 suagencyter.m@gmail.com      <NA>
5 susgho.agency@gmail.com   .agency
```

Data:

```
df=read.table(text="email
           susgho.agency@gmail.com
           suagencyter.m@gmail.com
           duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com
           ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com
           gjhfhg1-ail.com",h=T)

df2=read.table(text=" pattern
              .agency
              .abc
              1-ail.com",h=T)
```

Comment: ````stack(setNames(Vectorize(grep)(df2$pattern,df,value=T,fixed=T),df2$pattern))```` could also be ````stack(setNames(mapply(grep,df2$pattern,df,value=T,fixed=T),df2$pattern))```` as Vectorize is a wrapper for mapply

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. But I am getting the error Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?).

Comment: @user3642360 You have huge data probably, why not try using some packages? eg stringr? I guess that would work. I am not quite sure. Which of the two methods gives you an error?

Comment: yes my data has 500k rows. The first method is giving me error. the second one is taking forever to execute. How can I use stringr package in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach using `stringr::str_match`, though you need to escape the special characters in the `pattern` strings first, by adding the double-backslash prefix:

```
email=c("susgho.agency@gmail.com","suagencyter.m@gmail.com",
        "duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com","ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com",
        "gjhfhg1-ail.com","gjhgkjhgbrt.gh@aol.com")

pattern=c("\\.agency","\\.abc","1\\-ail.com")

data.frame(email, pattern = stringr::str_match(email, paste(pattern, collapse = "|")))
```

This produces the following output:

```
                    email   pattern
1 susgho.agency@gmail.com   .agency
2 suagencyter.m@gmail.com      <NA>
3 duff.abcnkhgt@gmail.com      .abc
4    ftyhabcdfg@gmail.com      <NA>
5         gjhfhg1-ail.com 1-ail.com
6  gjhgkjhgbrt.gh@aol.com      <NA>
```